# Javascript works in HTML file but not in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to add the timer to my code. The problem is the code works perfectly fine when used inside HTML, but when i tried to use it in an external javascript file it is not working. Help me out

I tried using inside HTML code , it works perfect, But not in as a seperate Javascript file

```
<div> Time :<span id ="timer"></span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeoutHandle;
    function countdown(minutes, seconds) {
        function tick() {
            var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
            counter.innerHTML =
                minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
            seconds--;
            if (seconds >= 0) {
                timeoutHandle = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
            } else {
                if (minutes >= 1) {
                    // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by Victor Streithorst
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        countdown(minutes - 1, 59);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
            if (seconds==0 && minutes ==0){

              alert("Game over");
              reset();
            }
        }
        tick();
    }

    countdown(1, 00);
</script>
```

this is the code used inside HTML. but when i tried using it in the external Js file, it is not working.

```
  <script src="game.js"></script>
```

the above is the external Js file. Help me out with this problem

Comment: do you see any error in the console ?

Comment: did you take out the script tags?

Comment: @ControlAltDel i removed the script tags while moving the code to external JS file

Comment: @ControlAltDel could you show me how to do it with onload listener.....

Comment: could you show us the html after having modified the tag please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the JS in the `window.onload = function() { }`

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var timeoutHandle;
    function countdown(minutes, seconds) {
        function tick() {
            var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
            counter.innerHTML =
                minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
            seconds--;
            if (seconds >= 0) {
                timeoutHandle = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
            } else {
                if (minutes >= 1) {
                    // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by Victor Streithorst
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        countdown(minutes - 1, 59);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
            if (seconds==0 && minutes ==0){

              alert("Game over");
              reset();
            }
        }
        tick();
    }

    countdown(1, 00); }
```

```html
 <div> Time :<span id="timer"></span></div>
```

The javascript code was running before the DOM was constructed. Wrapping it in the window.onload function makes sure it waits for DOM construction

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is where your script is loading. On your HTML page, it is loading and running after you've declared your timer element. When you moved this to an external javascript file, it probably isn't waiting for the element to be created and set up. You should move the call to countdown into a document onload listener

Comment: you can also add the `defer` attribute to the tag if your target is not opera mini or younger than 2013

Comment: What error message did you get when it is not working?